# Getting around the constraint "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate

I'm using Postgres, which enforces the constraint that all columns in a SELECT...GROUP BY must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Lets say I'm modelling peoples' cars, and I want to work out a person's name, license number, and how many cars they have. Here's my example as an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/34318/3).

I would have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE license(
  person_id integer REFERENCES person(id),
  expiry_date date
);

CREATE TABLE car(
  owner_id integer REFERENCES person(id),
  registration_number TEXT
);
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT person.name, person.id, license.expiry_date, COUNT(car) FROM person
  JOIN license ON license.person_id = person.id
  JOIN car ON car.owner_id = person.id
WHERE person.name = 'Charles Bannerman'
GROUP BY person.id;
```

I *know*, because of my own business logic, that **one person can only have one license**, so when I join to the person, even though it's GROUP BY'd, I should be able to find their license number. However because it isn't part of the GROUP BY statement and doesn't use an aggregate function, I can't access it.

How should I write this query in an idiomatic way. I've seen vague things about LATERAL JOINs, window functions, and subqueries, but I'm not sure the best way to answer this question.

Comment: Haven't really read the question, but this sort of thing often turns out to be people looking for `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: If you know that there is only one person.name and license.expiry_date for each person_id, you could do `SELECT MAX(person.name), person.id, MAX(license.expiry_date), COUNT(car) FROM person` without losing anything in result - although it is not very clever solution.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that a lot unfortunately. It gets very messy when you need to do it to a lot of columns though

Comment: Alternatively you could of course group also by `person.name` and `license.expiry_date`...

Comment: If grouping/aggregating on the "rest" of the columns is not an option, I might myself go for a subquery to calculate the count of cars and thus get rid of the grouping in the main query. However, I suspect that it might not perform as well on large data sets as a single query with "unnecessary" grouping/aggregation.

Comment: If the `license` table had a primary key (why doesn't it have one?), you can use `group by person.id, license.id` because the ungrouped columns are then functionally dependent on the two primary keys.

Comment: In my actual database (this is just a fabricated example), the license table is actually just a lookup table that maps one string to another. It doesn't make sense on its own, hence it doesn't have a primary key

Comment: You state that "*one person can only have one license*" so why is `person_id` not a primary key in the `license` table then?

Answer (score 1):

seharusnya seperti ini(supposed to be like this):

```
SELECT person.name, person.id, license.expiry_date, COUNT(car) FROM person
  JOIN license ON license.person_id = person.id
  JOIN car ON car.owner_id = person.id
WHERE person.name = 'Charles Bannerman'
GROUP BY person.name, person.id, license.expiry_date, car.car;
```

Comment: Grouping by `car.car` is superfluous here since it is aggregated by `COUNT`.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this approach. Using a GROUP BY on every column is slower, less maintainable, and can create more groups than necessary because I only *want* to group on person.id. http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 1):

You could `GROUP BY` before you do any joining...  Which means, reverse your query.

This is your OLD query

```
SELECT person.name, person.id, license.expiry_date, COUNT(car) FROM person
  JOIN license ON license.person_id = person.id
  JOIN car ON car.owner_id = person.id
WHERE person.name = 'Charles Bannerman'
GROUP BY person.id;
```

This is your NEW query

```
WITH vals AS (
  SELECT owner_id, COUNT(car) AS cars FROM car GROUP BY owner_id
) SELECT
  person.name, person.id, license.expiry_date, vals.cars
FROM cars
JOIN person ON cars.owner_id = person.id
JOIN license ON person.id = license.person_id
WHERE person.name = 'Charles Bannerman';
```

That solution may not be as efficient as you want... Another potential solution would be to write a plpgsql function to return the count of cars when given a person_id..

The solution I would choose would depend on the use case of the query..  Will the query ALWAYS be used to return a single row of data (for a specific person)?..  Or will it be used in a report to display many rows?..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person.name, 
       person.id, 
       license.expiry_date, COUNT(car) OVER (Partition by Person.Id)
FROM person
  JOIN license ON license.person_id = person.id
  JOIN car ON car.owner_id = person.id
WHERE person.name = 'Charles Bannerman';
```

You can use `OVER (partion by <grouping column(s)>)`.  This will aggregate the data with out having to use a Group by.

The only drawback to this is if there are duplicate `Person.id` and `license.expiry_date` you will get 2 results.  But you can add any other data without having it be part of the `group by`.  Just a thought.

Comment: I think that drawback is a pretty big problem. As you say, with that query on the SQL Fiddle I get 2 identical rows. I know I could SELECT DISTINCT but I wonder about the efficiency of that.